# knockout view model wrapped in observable

Tags: view, model, knockout.js, observable

To avoid calling applyBindings multiple times on the same DOM element, I wrap my various viewmodels in an observable. then just change that observable to whatever view model i wanna see and BAM...that works.

until i do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="if:$data">
...some bindings in here
</div>
```

when i change view models, the bindings inside any "if:$data" blocks do not update.

here's a fiddle to really demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/btrauma8/2TxME/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have worked properly prior to KO 2.2.  In 2.2, we made `if` and `ifnot` more efficient by only re-rendering the section when the value actually changes between truthy/falsy.

There were many cases where people would bind against something like `if: items().length` and the entire section would be re-rendered everytime that an item was added.

In your case, you can overcome this pretty easily by just using the `with` binding instead of `if`.  Since, you are binding against `$data`, it will not actually change the context and will give you the result that you are after.